# How to write a recursive factorial function in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, recursion, lisp, factorial

I just want some help with how to write a recursive factorial function in Ruby. I have the following code which is lisp, but I want to do the same thing in Ruby.

```lisp
(defun factorial (N)
    (if (= N 1) 1
        (* N (factorial (- N 1)))))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58643287/how-to-write-a-recursive-factorial-function-in-ruby

Comment: I was about to ask you why you linked my own question, but then I realised lol. Bravo!

Comment: @Fab this is an exact duplicate!

Comment: Logic error: 0! = 1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how to write the your code in ruby:

```
def factorial(n)
  return 1 if n == 1
  n * factorial(n - 1)
end

factorial(5)
#=> 120
factorial(7)
#=> 5040
```

*Edit for Stefan's comment:*

To avoid a `SystemStackError` error with large values of `n`, use the [tail-recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) method. Also Ruby's `tailcall` optimization must be enabled.

```
# before edit
factorial(100_000).to_s.size
#=> stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

To avoid `SystemStackError`

```
RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile_option = {
  tailcall_optimization: true,
  trace_instruction: false
}

RubyVM::InstructionSequence.new(<<-CODE).eval
  def factorial(n, acc = 1)
    return acc if n == 1
    factorial(n - 1, n * acc)
  end
CODE

puts factorial(100_000).to_s.size
#=> 456574
```

[Resource 1](https://rpanachi.com/2016/05/30/ruby-recursion-stack-size-tail-call-optimization)
[Resource 2](https://gist.github.com/sfcgeorge/4b9d26073c28ba3dc66d)

Comment: Or if you where to translate the lisp code more literally: `n == 1 ? 1 : n * factorial(n - 1)`, but I prefer the guard version myself.

Comment: Not sure about Lisp, but this Ruby version will cause a stack overflow for large values of `n`. You could turn it into a [tail-recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) method and enable Ruby's tail call optimization.